# Is it possible to override any Methods from in built .net core code

Tags: c#, .net-core

Is it possible to override any coding in  .net core in build .. ?
Not for any specific example. I'm just asking generally because .net core was open source.. that's why I've this doubt

Comment: Well, yes, theoretically you can rewrite the code, because it is open. And compile your own library instead of the standard one.

Comment: You can also replace the code on the fly using tools such as Harmony or MethodRedirect. It may be difficult, but it is feasible.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov but that's not what we colloquially mean when we say "override".

Comment: @Fildor Not officially, but many years ago I saw a [whitepaper on SANS website](https://www.sans.org/white-papers/) talking about how it could be done, dunno if that GAC assemblies shadow copy was patched or not. Anyway, I lost the paper and it is no longer on that site so...

Comment: In addition, right during execution, you can intercept events generated by the CLR environment (see ETW events) and redirect calls to your own methods.

Comment: @Fildor - Yeah, but the author mentions open source. Perhaps he is interested in rewriting the code completely.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov I am in doubt OP even has the correct understanding of either term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Many classes can be inherited, which allows you to override virtual methods. You can add extension methods to add new methods. And you can write your own classes from scratch.

But there is plenty of functionality within .NET that you cannot override.